# Spyder 5.4.2 has very wide ribbon menu bars on high resolution screen (however icon sizes are fine)

Tags: spyder, display, resolution, monitor

When I load up Spyder 5.4.2 on my large monitor (using high resolution) Spyder has large ribbon menu bars as shown in the screenshot. I have tried varying options Preferences->Application-> Changing DPI settings, modifying margins etc...

If I open Spyder on a lower resolution monitor it doesn't have this problem. If then unplug this and plug into high resolution monitor with the 'Enable auto high DPI scaling' set to true it looks fine.

Can anyone suggest a way of loading spyder, so it displays correctly.

Please follow the link to the attached an image showing the wide menu bar.
[Image showing Spyder interface problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHdgY.png)

Comment: It's a year later, and now I'm having this same problem on my new build.  The menu is too wide, font on address, file tabs, and everything in the Preferences UI are twice the size they should be.  Any solution?